# Ninject's InSingletonScope() creating more than one instance

Tags: c#, ninject

We're having a problem with a Ninject singleton scope class being constructed more than once. I've reduced our code to an example exhibiting the strange behahiour. Handler is a singleton which is composed of a Module with a somewhat complex initialization, which is performed by the Handler constructor. That's the reason for the Module binding using ToMethod(). Part is also a singleton and it is very important that the Handler is created if a Part is created, that's why we request a Handler in the Part OnActivation callback.

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<Handler>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind<Module>().ToMethod(x => x.Kernel.Get<Handler>().Module);
kernel.Bind<Part>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope().OnActivation(_ => kernel.Get<Handler>());
```

The full code including some debug outputs:

```
    [Test]
    public void NinjectShouldCreateOnlyOneHandler()
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Handler>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
        kernel.Bind<Module>().ToMethod(x =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Module ToMethod enter");
            Module module = x.Kernel.Get<Handler>().Module;
            Debug.WriteLine("Module ToMethod exit");
            return module;
        });
        kernel.Bind<Part>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope().OnActivation(_ =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Part OnActivation enter");
            kernel.Get<Handler>();
            Debug.WriteLine("Part OnActivation exit");
        });

        Debug.WriteLine("Get<Module>()");
        kernel.Get<Module>();
        Debug.WriteLine($"InstanceCount = {Handler.InstanceCount}");
        Assert.AreEqual(1, Handler.InstanceCount);
    }

    public class Handler
    {
        public static int InstanceCount { get; private set; } = 0;

        public Handler(Part part)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Handler ctor, InstanceCount = {++InstanceCount}");
            Module = new Module(part);
        }

        public Module Module { get; }
    }

    public class Module
    {
        public Module(Part part)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Module ctor");
        }
    }

    public class Part
    {
        public Part()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Part ctor");
        }
    }
```

The debug output:

```
Get<Module>()
Module ToMethod enter
Part ctor
Part OnActivation enter
Handler ctor, InstanceCount = 1
Module ctor
Part OnActivation exit
Handler ctor, InstanceCount = 2
Module ctor
Module ToMethod exit
InstanceCount = 2
```

I guess the problem is that we request a Handler instance while it is being created, but since it can be constructed at that point - why isn't that instance used for the next request?

I would expect that Ninject would rather throw an exception instead of creating two instances of a singleton scope class. Is this a bug or is there something I've missed? We're using Ninject v3.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular dependency when creating the objects.

Ninject is *trying* to create only one instance of `Handler` but it can't because when trying to instantiate `Handler`, it needs a `Part` instance and a step in creating `Part` is getting an instance of `Handler` (the OnActiviation action for `Part`).

Comment: Yes, but a Handler *can* be created inside the OnActivation callback and I don't understand why it isn't stored and returned to the original request instead of creating another one? Also, if Ninject can't do what I tell it to do, I expect it to throw an exception instead of creating multiple instances of a class marked as singleton. I guess I need to report this to the Ninject developers.